# Changing the border in a GroupBox component

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change the border thickness of a Groupbox on a windows form in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997977/how-can-i-change-the-border-thickness-of-a-groupbox-on-a-windows-form-in-c)

Guys

I am using groupbox' in Visual studio. But the Border in the groupbox is to small. I was wondering if there is a way to edit the border by giving it a color or maybe a thicker edge?

[image]

As u can see in the image it is very hard to see the border around it.

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997977/how-can-i-change-the-border-thickness-of-a-groupbox-on-a-windows-form-in-c

Comment: Check this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/cfd34dd1-b6e5-4b56-9901-0dc3d2ca5788/changing-border-color-of-groupbox?forum=winforms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can Use This:

```
using System.Drawing;
```

using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myGroupBox myGroupBox = new myGroupBox();
        myGroupBox.Text = "GroupBox1";

        this.Controls.Add(myGroupBox);

    }




    public static GraphicsPath CreatePath(float x, float y, float width, float height,
                                  float radius, bool RoundTopLeft, bool RoundTopRight, bool RoundBottomRight, bool RoundBottomLeft)
    {
        float xw = x + width;
        float yh = y + height;
        float xwr = xw - radius;
        float yhr = yh - radius;
        float xr = x + radius;
        float yr = y + radius;
        float r2 = radius * 2;
        float xwr2 = xw - r2;
        float yhr2 = yh - r2;

        GraphicsPath p = new GraphicsPath();
        p.StartFigure();

        //Top Left Corner

        if (RoundTopLeft)
        {
            p.AddArc(x, y, r2, r2, 180, 90);
        }
        else
        {
            p.AddLine(x, yr, x, y);
            p.AddLine(x, y, xr, y);

        }

        //Top Edge
        p.AddLine(xr, y, xwr, y);

        //Top Right Corner

        if (RoundTopRight)
        {
            p.AddArc(xwr2, y, r2, r2, 270, 90);
        }
        else
        {
            p.AddLine(xwr, y, xw, y);
            p.AddLine(xw, y, xw, yr);
        }


        //Right Edge
        p.AddLine(xw, yr, xw, yhr);

        //Bottom Right Corner

        if (RoundBottomRight)
        {
            p.AddArc(xwr2, yhr2, r2, r2, 0, 90);
        }
        else
        {
            p.AddLine(xw, yhr, xw, yh);
            p.AddLine(xw, yh, xwr, yh);
        }


        //Bottom Edge
        p.AddLine(xwr, yh, xr, yh);

        //Bottom Left Corner           

        if (RoundBottomLeft)
        {
            p.AddArc(x, yhr2, r2, r2, 90, 90);
        }
        else
        {
            p.AddLine(xr, yh, x, yh);
            p.AddLine(x, yh, x, yhr);
        }

        //Left Edge
        p.AddLine(x, yhr, x, yr);

        p.CloseFigure();
        return p;
    }


    class myGroupBox : GroupBox
    {
        public myGroupBox()
        {
            base.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

        }
        [Browsable(false)]
        public override Color BackColor
        {
            get
            {
                return base.BackColor;
            }
            set
            {
                base.BackColor = value;
            }
        }

        private Color backColor = Color.Transparent;

        public Color ActualBackColor
        {
            get { return this.backColor; }

            set { this.backColor = value; }
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {

            Size tSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(this.Text, this.Font);

            Rectangle borderRect = e.ClipRectangle;

            borderRect.Y += tSize.Height / 2;

            borderRect.Height -= tSize.Height / 2;

            GraphicsPath gPath = CreatePath(0, borderRect.Y, (float)(this.Width - 1), borderRect.Height - 1, 5, true, true, true, true);

            e.Graphics.FillPath(new SolidBrush(ActualBackColor), gPath);

            e.Graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(Color.Red), gPath);

            borderRect.X += 6;
            borderRect.Y -= 7;

            e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor), borderRect);
        }
    }
```